# Third Person Controller for UFO glb model

Tags: javascript, three.js

currently trying to apply a tutorial I found for creating character controls / a third person camera. After a few hours of trial and error I have finally imported the model into the scene and created keyboard controls that are registering into the console. Now i just need to find a way to connect the two. I believe im very close, but as of now i am unsure of where to go.

```js
import './style.css'
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import {OrbitControls} from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';


class UFOControllerProxy {
  constructor(animations) {
    this._animations = animations;
  }

  get animations() {
    return this._animations;
  }
};


class UFOController {
  constructor(params) {
    this._Init(params);
  }

  _Init(params) {
    this._params = params;
    this._decceleration = new THREE.Vector3(-0.0005, -0.0001, -5.0);
    this._acceleration = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0.25, 50.0);
    this._velocity = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    this._position = new THREE.Vector3();

    this._animations = {};
    this._input = new UFOControllerInput();
    this._stateMachine = new ufoFSM(
        new UFOControllerProxy(this._animations));

    this._LoadModels();
  }

  _LoadModels() {
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('UFO/retroUFO.glb', (glb) => {
      // glb.scale
      // glb.traverse(c => {
      //   // c.castShadow = true;
      // });

      this._target = glb.scene.children[0];
      this._params.scene.add(this._target);

      this._mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(this._target);

      this._manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
      this._manager.onLoad = () => {
        this._stateMachine.SetState('idle');
      };

      const _OnLoad = (animName, anim) => {
        const clip = anim.animations[0];
        const action = this._mixer.clipAction(clip);
  
        this._animations[animName] = {
          clip: clip,
          action: action,
        };
      };

      
      
    });
  }

  get Position() {
    return this._position;
  }

  get Rotation() {
    if (!this._target) {
      return new THREE.Quaternion();
    }
    return this._target.quaternion;
  }

  Update(timeInSeconds) {
    if (!this._stateMachine._currentState) {
      return;
    }

    this._stateMachine.Update(timeInSeconds, this._input);

    const velocity = this._velocity;
    const frameDecceleration = new THREE.Vector3(
        velocity.x * this._decceleration.x,
        velocity.y * this._decceleration.y,
        velocity.z * this._decceleration.z
    );
    frameDecceleration.multiplyScalar(timeInSeconds);
    frameDecceleration.z = Math.sign(frameDecceleration.z) * Math.min(
        Math.abs(frameDecceleration.z), Math.abs(velocity.z));

    velocity.add(frameDecceleration);

    const controlObject = this._target;
    const _Q = new THREE.Quaternion();
    const _A = new THREE.Vector3();
    const _R = controlObject.quaternion.clone();

    const acc = this._acceleration.clone();
    if (this._input._keys.shift) {
      acc.multiplyScalar(2.0);
    }

    // if (this._stateMachine._currentState.Name == 'dance') {
    //   acc.multiplyScalar(0.0);
    // }

    if (this._input._keys.forward) {
      velocity.z += acc.z * timeInSeconds;
    }
    if (this._input._keys.backward) {
      velocity.z -= acc.z * timeInSeconds;
    }
    if (this._input._keys.left) {
      _A.set(0, 1, 0);
      _Q.setFromAxisAngle(_A, 4.0 * Math.PI * timeInSeconds * this._acceleration.y);
      _R.multiply(_Q);
    }
    if (this._input._keys.right) {
      _A.set(0, 1, 0);
      _Q.setFromAxisAngle(_A, 4.0 * -Math.PI * timeInSeconds * this._acceleration.y);
      _R.multiply(_Q);
    }

    controlObject.quaternion.copy(_R);

    const oldPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
    oldPosition.copy(controlObject.position);

    const forward = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
    forward.applyQuaternion(controlObject.quaternion);
    forward.normalize();

    const sideways = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
    sideways.applyQuaternion(controlObject.quaternion);
    sideways.normalize();

    sideways.multiplyScalar(velocity.x * timeInSeconds);
    forward.multiplyScalar(velocity.z * timeInSeconds);

    controlObject.position.add(forward);
    controlObject.position.add(sideways);

    this._position.copy(controlObject.position);

    if (this._mixer) {
      this._mixer.update(timeInSeconds);
    }
  }
};

class UFOControllerInput {
  constructor() {
    this._Init();    
  }

  _Init() {
    this._keys = {
      forward: false,
      backward: false,
      left: false,
      right: false,
      space: false,
      shift: false,
    };
    console.log(this._keys)
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => this._onKeyDown(e), false);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => this._onKeyUp(e), false);
  }

  _onKeyDown(event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 87: // w
        this._keys.forward = true;
        break;
      case 65: // a
        this._keys.left = true;
        break;
      case 83: // s
        this._keys.backward = true;
        break;
      case 68: // d
        this._keys.right = true;
        break;
      case 32: // SPACE
        this._keys.space = true;
        break;
      case 16: // SHIFT
        this._keys.shift = true;
        break;
    }
    console.log(event)
  }

  _onKeyUp(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
      case 87: // w
        this._keys.forward = false;
        break;
      case 65: // a
        this._keys.left = false;
        break;
      case 83: // s
        this._keys.backward = false;
        break;
      case 68: // d
        this._keys.right = false;
        break;
      case 32: // SPACE
        this._keys.space = false;
        break;
      case 16: // SHIFT
        this._keys.shift = false;
        break;
    }
    console.log(event)
  }
};


class FiniteStateMachine {
  constructor() {
    this._states = {};
    this._currentState = null;
  }

  _AddState(name, type) {
    this._states[name] = type;
  }

  SetState(name) {
    const prevState = this._currentState;
    
    if (prevState) {
      if (prevState.Name == name) {
        return;
      }
      prevState.Exit();
    }

    const state = new this._states[name](this);

    this._currentState = state;
    state.Enter(prevState);
  }

  Update(timeElapsed, input) {
    if (this._currentState) {
      this._currentState.Update(timeElapsed, input);
    }
  }
};


class ufoFSM extends FiniteStateMachine {
  constructor(proxy) {
    super();
    this._proxy = proxy;
    this._Init();
  }

  _Init() {
    this._AddState('idle', IdleState);
    this._AddState('fly', flyState);
  }
};


class State {
  constructor(parent) {
    this._parent = parent;
  }

  Enter() {}
  Exit() {}
  Update() {}
};




class flyState extends State {
  constructor(parent) {
    super(parent);
  }

  get Name() {
    return 'fly';
  }

  Enter(prevState) {
    const curAction = this._parent._proxy._animations['fly'].action;
    if (prevState) {
      const prevAction = this._parent._proxy._animations[prevState.Name].action;

      curAction.enabled = true;

      if (prevState.Name == 'run') {
        const ratio = curAction.getClip().duration / prevAction.getClip().duration;
        curAction.time = prevAction.time * ratio;
      } else {
        curAction.time = 0.0;
        curAction.setEffectiveTimeScale(1.0);
        curAction.setEffectiveWeight(1.0);
      }

      curAction.crossFadeFrom(prevAction, 0.5, true);
      curAction.play();
    } else {
      curAction.play();
    }
  }

  Exit() {
  }

  Update(timeElapsed, input) {
    if (input._keys.forward || input._keys.backward) {
      if (input._keys.shift) {
        this._parent.SetState('run');
      }
      return;
    }

    this._parent.SetState('idle');
  }
};

class IdleState extends State {
  constructor(parent) {
    super(parent);
  }

  get Name() {
    return 'idle';
  }

  Enter(prevState) {
    const idleAction = this._parent._proxy._animations['idle'].action;
    if (prevState) {
      const prevAction = this._parent._proxy._animations[prevState.Name].action;
      idleAction.time = 0.0;
      idleAction.enabled = true;
      idleAction.setEffectiveTimeScale(1.0);
      idleAction.setEffectiveWeight(1.0);
      idleAction.crossFadeFrom(prevAction, 0.5, true);
      idleAction.play();
    } else {
      idleAction.play();
    }
  }

  Exit() {
  }

  Update(_, input) {
    if (input._keys.forward || input._keys.backward) {
      this._parent.SetState('fly');
    }
  }
};



class UFOThirdPersonCamera {
  constructor(params) {
    this._params = params;
    this._camera = params.camera;

    this._currentPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
    this._currentLookat = new THREE.Vector3();
  }
 


  _CalculateIdealOffset() {
    const idealOffset = new THREE.Vector3(-4, 10, -20);
    idealOffset.applyQuaternion(this._params.target.Rotation);
    idealOffset.add(this._params.target.Position);
    return idealOffset;
  }

  _CalculateIdealLookat() {
    const idealLookat = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 10);
    idealLookat.applyQuaternion(this._params.target.Rotation);
    idealLookat.add(this._params.target.Position);
    return idealLookat;
  }

  Update(timeElapsed) {
    const idealOffset = this._CalculateIdealOffset();
    const idealLookat = this._CalculateIdealLookat();

    // const t = 0.05;
    // const t = 4.0 * timeElapsed;
    const t = 1.0 - Math.pow(0.001, timeElapsed);

    this._currentPosition.lerp(idealOffset, t);
    this._currentLookat.lerp(idealLookat, t);

    this._camera.position.copy(this._currentPosition);
    this._camera.lookAt(this._currentLookat);
  }
}


class UFOThirdPersonCameraDemo {
  constructor() {
    this._Initialize();
  }

  _Initialize() {
    this._threejs = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true,
    });
    this._threejs.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
    // this._threejs.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    // this._threejs.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
    this._threejs.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    this._threejs.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    document.body.appendChild(this._threejs.domElement);

    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      this._OnWindowResize();
    }, false);

    const fov = 75;
    const aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
    const near = 1.0;
    const far = 1000.0;
    this._camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
    this._camera.position.set(5, -5, 0);

    this._scene = new THREE.Scene();

    let light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF, 1.0);
    light.position.set(-100, 100, 100);
    light.target.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    // light.castShadow = true;
    // light.shadow.bias = -0.001;
    // light.shadow.mapSize.width = 4096;
    // light.shadow.mapSize.height = 4096;
    // light.shadow.camera.near = 0.1;
    // light.shadow.camera.far = 500.0;
    // light.shadow.camera.near = 0.5;
    // light.shadow.camera.far = 500.0;
    // light.shadow.camera.left = 50;
    // light.shadow.camera.right = -50;
    // light.shadow.camera.top = 50;
    // light.shadow.camera.bottom = -50;
    this._scene.add(light);

    light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.25);
    this._scene.add(light);

    const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    const texture = loader.load(['images/space.jpeg'   
    ]);
    texture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
    //this._scene.background = texture;


    
    //creating stars
const starVertices = []
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
  const x = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10000
  const y = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10000
  const z = -Math.random()* 10000
  starVertices.push(x, y, z)
}
const starGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry(2, 50, 50)
const starMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  color: 0xfff504,
  
})

//placing stars
const stars = new THREE.Points(starGeometry, starMaterial)
starGeometry.setAttribute('position', 
new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(
  starVertices, 3))
  this._scene.add(stars)


//creating stars
const starVertices2 = []
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
  const x = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10000
  const y = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10000
  const z = -Math.random() * -10000
  starVertices2.push(x, y, z)
}
const starGeometry2 = new THREE.BufferGeometry(2, 50, 50)
const starMaterial2 = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  color: 0x00ffff,
 
})

//placing stars
const stars2 = new THREE.Points(starGeometry2, starMaterial2)
starGeometry2.setAttribute('position', 
new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(
  starVertices2, 3))
  this._scene.add(stars2)

// //////////////////////////////
  const starVertices3 = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
    const x = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10000
    const y = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10000
    const z = -Math.random()* 10000
    starVertices3.push(x, y, z)
  }
  const starGeometry3 = new THREE.BufferGeometry(4, 50, 50)
  const starMaterial3 = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
  })
  
  //placing stars
  const stars3 = new THREE.Points(starGeometry3, starMaterial3)
  starGeometry3.setAttribute('position', 
  new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(
    starVertices3, 3))
    this._scene.add(stars3)
  
  
  //creating stars
  const starVertices4 = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
    const x = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10000
    const y = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10000
    const z = -Math.random() * 10000
    starVertices2.push(x, y, z)
  }
  const starGeometry4 = new THREE.BufferGeometry(2, 50, 50)
  const starMaterial4 = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    color: 0x00ffff,
   
  })
  
  //placing stars
  const stars4 = new THREE.Points(starGeometry4, starMaterial4)
  starGeometry4.setAttribute('position', 
  new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(
    starVertices4, 3))
    this._scene.add(stars4)

    const plane = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100, 10, 10),
        new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
            color: 0x808080,
          }));
    plane.castShadow = false;
    plane.receiveShadow = true;
    plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
    //this._scene.add(plane);

  

    this._mixers = [];
    this._previousRAF = null;

    this._LoadAnimatedModel();
    this._RAF();
  }

  _LoadAnimatedModel() {
    const params = {
      camera: this._camera,
      scene: this._scene,
    }
    this._controls = new UFOController(params);

    this._thirdPersonCamera = new UFOThirdPersonCamera({
      camera: this._camera,
      target: this._controls,
    });
  }

  _OnWindowResize() {
    this._camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    this._camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    this._threejs.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  }

  _RAF() {
    requestAnimationFrame((t) => {
      if (this._previousRAF === null) {
        this._previousRAF = t;
      }

      this._RAF();

      this._threejs.render(this._scene, this._camera);
      this._Step(t - this._previousRAF);
      this._previousRAF = t;
    });
  }

  _Step(timeElapsed) {
    const timeElapsedS = timeElapsed * 0.001;
    if (this._mixers) {
      this._mixers.map(m => m.update(timeElapsedS));
    }

    if (this._controls) {
      this._controls.Update(timeElapsedS);
    }

    this._thirdPersonCamera.Update(timeElapsedS);
  }
}


let _APP = null;

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  _APP = new UFOThirdPersonCameraDemo();
});


function _LerpOverFrames(frames, t) {
  const s = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
  const e = new THREE.Vector3(100, 0, 0);
  const c = s.clone();

  for (let i = 0; i < frames; i++) {
    c.lerp(e, t);
  }
  return c;
}

function _TestLerp(t1, t2) {
  const v1 = _LerpOverFrames(100, t1);
  const v2 = _LerpOverFrames(50, t2);
  console.log(v1.x + ' | ' + v2.x);
}

_TestLerp(0.01, 0.01);
_TestLerp(1.0 / 100.0, 1.0 / 50.0);
_TestLerp(1.0 - Math.pow(0.3, 1.0 / 100.0), 
          1.0 - Math.pow(0.3, 1.0 / 50.0));
```

Comment: Also if anyone wants to test - the 3d ufo model is available on the free 3D viewer library under the scifi section. Thanks!